# How to draw a control flow graph for a nested for loop?

Tags: for-loop, cyclomatic-complexity, control-flow-graph

```
for(num2 = 0; num2 <= 3;  num2++)
{
  for(num1 = 0; num1 <= 2; num1++)
  {
        cout<< num2<< "   " << num1<< endl;
  }
}
```

how to draw a control flow graph for the above code segment?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

I am studying for a test on this and it's still kind of vague, so I might be wrong, but I think it should be this:

```
  O<
 /| \
/ v /
| O<
| | \
| v /
| O
\
 >O
```

Please let me know if you got the same result, or if the graph is unclear I'll make a proper one.